# What is a (the?) minimal logger.properties that turns off all logging?

Tags: log4cxx

I have an application that uses `log4cxx` internally, with dozens of loggers.   What is a minimal `logger.properties` that I can setup to turn off all logging output?

In particular I'm getting a warning like (no properties file present):

```
log4cxx: No appender could be found for logger (FileSource).
log4cxx: Please initialize the log4cxx system properly.
```

`FileSource` is a class that uses `log4cxx`.

My goal is to preclude all `log4cxx` output at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
  <root>
        <priority value="OFF" />
  </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

A simple logger.properties that logs to standard out could look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!-- add attribute  debug="true" to log4j:configuration tag to see how logger reads it's configuration. -->
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
  <appender name="ConsoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p %c (%F:%M:%L) - %m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
        <priority value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
  </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```